# What was the earliest plane in push-pull configuration that flew or at least took off?

Tags: aviation-history

I am looking for the earliest plane in push-pull configuration that flew or at least took off.

I have found such planes ("Short Triple Twin" and "Short Tandem Twin") [flown in 1911](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_S.27). So, I would be especially interested in push-pull flying machines that took off before 1911.

Comment: The Shorts S.27 was just a pusher unless you mean the Tandem Twin, are you asking about aircraft that have both pusher/tractor configurations? Like the [Cessna Skymaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_Skymaster) or just pushers?

Comment: The Wikipedia page I quoted also talks about two 1911 planes named "Short Triple Twin" and "Short Tandem Twin". Yes, am asking about planes that have a pusher-tractor configuration. I will modify the question to be more clear.

Comment: From what I can tell, the aircraft you referenced is the first flying example.

Answer (score 3):

**I have found a plane, that had both a pusher and a tractor propeller, which flew for the first time over Cotroceni airfield, Bucharest, Romania, on June 17, 1910.** Likely there are other planes like this that flew before.

[image: Vlaicu I plane during construction]
Vlaicu I plane during construction

[image: Newspaper article about Aurel Vlaicu's first flight July 17, 1910]
Newspaper article about Aurel Vlaicu's first flight June 17, 1910

Source: [A Vlaicu I - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Vlaicu_I)

Comment: I wonder how they found the gigantic rubber band to make it go? :)

Comment: The rubber band was a 50 hp Gnome Omega rotary engine similar to this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UBAukXPD-0

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in my studies, while working on a book about pusher aircraft, I came across this much earlier push-pull Russian aeroplane. I also have other examples of pusher and pusher-puller airplanes much earlier than 1910.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozhaysky%27s_airplane

Terrence Murphy

Comment: I believe the question is referring to the earliest push-pull plane that really flew in front of reliable witnesses. It is not clear whether Mozhaisky's airplane flew.

Comment: What other examples do you have?